# vim: how to remove 6 leader characters of a whole file?

Tags: vim, character, ex

I've got a text file like

```
00001 This is line 1
00002 This is line 2
10001 ??
30004 xccddd
```

I wish to delete the leading 6 characters of all lines. Is there a one line vim normal mode command that could do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can delete them by:

- `:%normal! 6x`

`%`: All lines of the file

`normal!`: Execute command in normal mode

`6x`: Delete 6 characters

or

- `:%s/^.\{6}//`

---

Comment: Thanks, both works fine, just curious about what does :%normal! mean?

Answer (score 3):

Just add a (recursive) macro solution to the family. It beats the `:s` and `:norm` commands in a "golf" way.. ^_^

```
qq6x+@qq@q
```

It uses a recursive macro so that we don't have to press something like `9999@q`.

Comment: I rarely see others use `+`/`<cr>` in macros, but it is my preferred method of going to the next line as it puts the cursor at the first non-black character. Cheers!

Comment: I am a `+/-` fan too, particularly in macro.  @PeterRincker

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answers, you can also use visual block mode.

- move cursor to first row, first character: `gg^`
- Invoke visual block mode: `Ctrl+v`
- Select the block to delete: `G6l`
  (`G` to go down to end of file, and then move right `l` six times)
- Delete the block: `x`